# Getting the intersection of two raster files using Pandas Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, pandas

I am trying to get the intersection (the overlap part) of two rasters but the thing is that by comparing them in a dataframe, I cannot find common points. I check on QGIS and there are common areas. Any suggestions?

***UPDATE***

So I am posting now how I open the .tif file and how I transform the data to a dataframe

```
def load_tiff(filename):
    """
    load data from a file
    """

    ndv, xsize, ysize, geot, projection, datatype = get_geo_info(filename)
    data = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(filename)
    data = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask=data == ndv, fill_value=ndv)

    return data , geot



def to_pandas(data, geot, name='value', dropna=True):
    """
    Convert to Pandas DataFrame, which can be easily exported to other types of files
    The DataFrame has the row, col, value, x, and y values for each cell
    Usage:
        data = array
        geot = georeferencing transform:
        
               geot[0] /* top left x */
               geot[1] /* w-e pixel resolution */
               geot[2] /* 0 */
               geot[3] /* top left y */
               geot[4] /* 0 */
               geot[5] /* n-s pixel resolution (negative value) */
               
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.stack(dropna=dropna)
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ['row', 'col', name]
    df['x'] = df.col.apply(lambda col: geot[0]+(col)*geot[1])
    df['y'] = df.row.apply(lambda row: geot[3]+(row)*geot[-1])
    return df
```

So the thing I thought of doing is to resample the data of the of the tif with the bigger cell size but I need to find a common starting point and start from there (Maybe the bigger top left point) and start the regression using nearest neighbor.But how I would remove areas that shouldn't have values and be NaN???

Comment: You probably mean `gdal`

Comment: @Taras I opened the tif with GDAL and made a pandas dataframe

Comment: @BERA I will add an update

Answer (score 3):

You're better off using rasterio. Get both raster's extents, intersect the extents, use the intersection to make windows, read data from where the rasters overlap using the windows.

```
from shapely.geometry import box
import rasterio as rio

with rio.open("raster1.tif") as ras1, rio.open("raster2.tif") as ras2:
    ext1 = box(*ras1.bounds) 
    ext2 = box(*ras2.bounds)
    intersection = ext1.intersection(ext2) 
    win1 = rio.windows.from_bounds(*intersection.bounds, ras1.transform)
    win2 = rio.windows.from_bounds(*intersection.bounds, ras2.transform)

    overlap_1 = ras1.read(window=win1)
    overlap_2 = ras2.read(window=win2)
```

And here's how to resample to the same pixel size based on the [rasterio resampling documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html):

```
from shapely.geometry import box
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling


with rio.open("raster1.tif") as ras1, rio.open("raster2_larger.tif") as ras2:
    x_scale = ras2.transform.a / ras1.transform.a
    y_scale = ras2.transform.e / ras1.transform.e

    # scale image transform
    transform = ras2.transform * ras2.transform.scale(
        (ras2.width / ras2.shape[-1]),
        (ras2.height / ras2.shape[-2])
    )

    ext1 = box(*ras1.bounds)
    ext2 = box(*ras2.bounds)
    intersection = ext1.intersection(ext2)
    win1 = rio.windows.from_bounds(*intersection.bounds, ras1.transform)
    win2 = rio.windows.from_bounds(*intersection.bounds, transform)

    overlap_1 = ras1.read(window=win1)
    overlap_2 = ras2.read(
        window=win2,
        out_shape=(
            ras2.count,
            int(win2.height * y_scale),
            int(win2.width * x_scale)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
    )

    print(overlap_1)
    print(overlap_2)
```

Comment: And how can I call the values in order to do some operations?? I want for example to compare them

Comment: `overlap_1` and `overlap_2` are numpy arrays. Standard array iteration is possible, but comparisons and operations don't require them. And a pandas dataframe is a poor choice for raster data.

Comment: And if you have different cell sizes like I see in your edit, but you didn't mention before, then you'll need to resample, which is very easy with rasterio.  But from your edit, I can see you have an [X Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), you're asking about something (X) which you think you need to do to solve Y when actually you should have just asked about Y.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean with your last comment. If you want edit your answer accordingly with my update. I added the code and presented my idea as a comment suggested me

Comment: You say "regression using nearest neighbor" in your edit. What are you *actually* trying to do? This is what I mean by the XY problem.  You're asking about how to get raster data into a `pd.Dataframe` because you want to do *something* with it, but a `df` is not a good way to handle raster data.